# Pass struct* from c# to c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, struct

The struct in c++ dll is defined like this:

```
struct WAVE_INFO {
    int channel_num;
    int audio_type;
    char *wave_data;
    int wave_length;
};
```

And the calling method like this:

```
extern "C" STRUCTDLL_API int processStruct(WAVE_INFO *pIn, WAVE_INFO *pOut);
```

The **wave_data** in my c# struct has to be **byte array (byte[])****, not char[] or string**. How should I defind the struct and the method in c# where the dll is called? And the length of wave_date is fixed, let's say like 100.

Comment: How do you know the length of the wave_data.  The length must be before the actual data so wave_data and wave_length should be reversed.

Comment: The length of the data is fixed, let's say like 100.

Comment: @jdweng Why should the length field in the struct come before the data field. That just determines the layout of the struct. The program can access the fields in whatever order it pleases.

Comment: The size of the structure has to be calculated from the data inside the structure.  So you always put the length of an array before the array. If you ever read any unix manuals like I have all the unix library methods have the length before the array.  When reading the structure without know the length of an array you can't find the end of the array so you can't get the length.  The properties are stored sequentially in memory with only the start location of the structure and the size of each property.  It is amazing how much you do not know.

Comment: Not in mixed languages.  The structure doesn't have a fixed size when passing to a c++ method.  The passing is done with only with a pointer to the start location.

Comment: @jdweng The struct has a fixed size. You can read and write its fields in whatever order you please. This isn't a variable length array where indeed the length must come first. The field here is a pointer to the array which is not part of the struct.

Comment: You mean audio wave data is FIXED size???????  It is always the same amount of time?????????

Comment: @jdweng No. I mean the struct `WAVE_INFO` has a fixed length. It is 16 bytes on a 32 bit platform, and 20 bytes on a 64 bit platform. Try asking a compiler and see if I'm wrong. The data length is variable, but remember that the data is not stored in the struct. A pointer to the data is stored in the struct.

Comment: I like unix a lot better.  Everything was done consistently and correctly.  Putting size after the actual data would never be done in unix.  The structure is confusing size wave_data could be the actual data or in this case fixed length info.  If it is really info it should be case wave_data_info, not wave_data.

Comment: @jdweng So you agree that I have been correct all along? And you are now retracting this sentence: *"It is amazing how much you do not know."* Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, I would say that the C++ struct is declared incorrectly. The payload is binary data so the array should be `unsigned char*` rather than `char*`.

Leaving that aside, the struct is a little fiddly to marshal because of the array. It goes something like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct WAVE_INFO
{
    public int channel_num;
    public int audio_type;
    public IntPtr wave_data;
    public int wave_length;
}
```

We can't use `byte[]` in the struct to be marshalled. Instead we have to declare the array as `IntPtr` and handle the marshalling ourselves. The cleanest way is to declare `byte[]` arrays and pin them with `GCHandle`.

The imported function looks like this:

```
[DllImport(dllfilename, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int processStruct(ref WAVE_INFO infoIn, ref WAVE_INFO infoOut);
```

And the rather messy call to the function goes like this:

```
var dataIn = new byte[256];
// populate the input data array
var dataOut = new byte[256];

GCHandle dataInHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(dataIn, GCHandleType.Pinned);
try
{
    GCHandle dataOutHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(dataOut, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try
    {
        WAVE_INFO infoIn;
        infoIn.audio_type = 1;
        infoIn.channel_num = 2;
        infoIn.wave_data = dataInHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        infoIn.wave_length = dataIn.Length;

        WAVE_INFO infoOut = new WAVE_INFO();
        infoOut.wave_data = dataOutHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        infoOut.wave_length = dataOut.Length;

        int retval = processStruct(ref infoIn, ref infoOut);
        // dataOut should have been populated by processStruct
    }
    finally
    {
        dataOutHandle.Free();
    }
}
finally
{
    dataInHandle.Free();
}
```

My assumption here is that the first parameter is used for input, and the second parameter for output. But that the onus is on the caller to allocate the wave data array for the output struct.

I've also assumed a calling convention, but you'd have to inspect the C++ macro `STRUCTDLL_API` to determine what the true calling convention is.

Comment: Thanks, David. I just tested with your code, and it works perfectly fine! Aprreciate your help.