# Pass a struct* from c# to c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, struct, dll

I want to pass a struct from my C# application to a function in a C++ dll.

In C++ the struct is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct _XSI_CONFIGURATION_FILE
{
    string*             pstrFileName;

}XSI_CONFIGURATION_FILE, *PXSI_CONFIGURATION_FILE;
```

and the function is defined like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) long XSIWrapperStopConfigurationFile(
            XSIContext uContext,
            unsigned long uNumberOfConfigurationFiles,
            XSI_CONFIGURATION_FILE * pConfigurationFile)
{
    return XSIStopConfigurationFile(uContext, uNumberOfConfigurationFiles, pConfigurationFile);
}
```

The closest thing to my issue I could find is this [Pass struct* from c# to c++ dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921321/pass-struct-from-c-sharp-to-c-dll) but he tries to pass a char array and i seem to have a string array so i dont even know how to correctly declare my struct in c# since I doubt I cannot just add an array of strings.

Note: I cannot change the c++ dll at all.

Edit:
My current stab at this looks like this:
Here is the Dll import delcaration:

```
[DllImport("XSIWrapper.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
unsafe public extern static int XSIWrapperStartConfigurationFile(
                            ulong uContext,
                            uint uNumberOfConfigurationFiles,
                            ref XSI_CONFIGURATION_FILE pConfigurationFile);
```

here is the function call:

```
public bool StartConfigurationFile(uint uNumberOfConfigurationFiles, XSI_CONFIGURATION_FILE[] ListofConfigurationFiles)
{
    int b = XSIWrapperStartConfigurationFile(uContext, uNumberOfConfigurationFiles, ref ListofConfigurationFiles[0]);
    if (b >= 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

and here is my structure:

```
public struct XSI_CONFIGURATION_FILE
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public System.String pstrFileName;

    public XSI_CONFIGURATION_FILE(String s)
    {
        pstrFileName = s;
    }
}
```

and I get an error message like this: "AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.".

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Edit 2:

Here is the allocation (just to test) of the array:

```
private int StartFile()
    {
        int returnvalue = 0;

        string strCnfgFile = strLocationName + "://TestScript.asf.xts";
        XSI_CONFIGURATION_FILE xsicnfgfile = new XSI_CONFIGURATION_FILE(strCnfgFile);

        XSI_CONFIGURATION_FILE[] xsicnfgfilelist = new XSI_CONFIGURATION_FILE[1];
        xsicnfgfilelist[0] = xsicnfgfile;

        m_communicator.StartConfigurationFile(1, xsicnfgfilelist);

        return returnvalue;
    }
```

Edit 3: I changed the context to ulong. A colleague told me that poiner size changed to 64 bit in x64. Also i marshalled the string in the struct differently. My code still does not work.

Comment: Should be a LPSTR (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings). A c++ string is a byte array terminated with a '\0'.  A c# string is a class object where each character can be one or two bytes.  Declaring as LPSTR the c++ byte array will be converted to a c# string.

Comment: @jdweng can i just add that to the structure or do i need to allocate something for my structure aswell?

Comment: c# is managed while c++ in unmanaged.  The compiler will automatically convert the structure from managed to unmanaged.

Comment: @jdweng I have edited my question with my current code. Could you please look over it? I am a bit lost here...

Comment: Where are you allocating the array XSI_CONFIGURATION_FILE[]

Comment: @jdweng I updated it

Comment: Does the c++ want the file name or the data inside the file?

Comment: The c++ wants the file name as string in the above mentioned structure. And then it seems to me as if it wants a pointer to an unspecified amount of this structure in order + an indicator of how much of these structures are given. I assumed I have to give a pointer to an array?

Comment: What is " XSIContext". Check documentation.  Is it an integer?  If the filename is an array then public System.String[] pstrFileName;  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323797/marshaling-pointer-to-an-array-of-strings

Comment: XSIContext is an integer in c# and depending on if its x86 or x64 its declared as an unsigned long or an unsigned __int64. Recently the Wrapper got updated to x64. On the c# side of things the other functions where i also have to provide the context uint still seems to work just fine. The pstrFileName in XSI_Configuration_FILE seems to me as if it is a pointer to a string. In the description it is described as single config file description.

Comment: You still have arrays in the Edit 2 that need to be changed.  The c++ has a pointer for the string to my first link you need to use MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256) instead of  MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)

Comment: See edit 3. I hope I made the changes to the string that you meant? It still does not work.

Comment: I really don't see anything wrong.  But just to be sure here are 2 changes 1) Add to structure [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] 2) Remove the method in the structure since you are not using the method.

Comment: Nope that did not work. Anyway thank you for your help and time.